# Custom Command line with html 5 and php5

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Cokeless shell</title>

<html>
<body>
<h1>H</h1> 


<form>
<action = "cokeshell.php">
            <input type = "text" name = "shell">

             <button type = "submit" name="submit">Click Here</button>
</form>




</body>
</html>
```

I'm working on a project using HTML5 and PHP5 where you have a form that if you type a certain keyword such as "IPV6 address" it'll give you the IPV4 address that you have. Do I need to use MYSQL or anything else beside PHP5?

Comment: Whats the question? *Do I need to use MYSQL*? No you dont.

Comment: Using forms will be blocky and you wont be able to achieve a real tty terminal, web sockets and something like xterm.js is a way better solution.

Comment: If I put help for list of commands/things to type and one of the commands was "ipconfig" (not really wanting to show an IP address) and if they put that in and when they did If I wanted it to say "hello" how could I achieve that using PHP5

Comment: Have conditions serverside, so if a user types help, you read that and respond with the data for typing help..

Comment: <?php
$coke = "help"
if $coke == "help": 
    print"ALL COMMANDS"
else: 
    print "OKI"
    ?>

Comment: this is my PHP script and when I type "help" and submit it with a form, nothing happens.

Comment: The link to my site is https://app-1515223044.000webhostapp.com